# How to make custom RSVP or multiple buttons in Gmail with schema.org?

Tags: gmail, schema.org, json-ld, google-schemas

I'd like to send emails in Gmail using schema.org email markup with more than one action.

For example: an email asking about attendance with 4 options: [late] [sick] [home] [vacation]

I tried adding options to the [rsvp action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action) but it appears to only allow Yes, No, Maybe.

So I tried to use type: EmailMessage, and make an array of potential actions, but it only creates a button for the first action in the list.

I don't mind if this UI does not appear in the summary, and only in the email body.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Gmail provides the three options for the RSVP action and other actions only support one (customisable) button.

A workaround is to use a single [view action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action) which takes you to a URL of your choice where you have the options you desire.

> ```
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {
>   "@context": "http://schema.org",
>   "@type": "EmailMessage",
>   "potentialAction": {
>     "@type": "ViewAction",
>     "target": "https://watch-movies.com/watch?movieId=abc123",
>     "name": "Watch movie"
>   },
>   "description": "Watch the 'Avengers' movie online"
> }
> </script>
> ```